# Is it possible to create a value in the TaxonomyHiddenList via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, taxonomy

I'm trying to update a library item using REST API. Some of the fields are Taxonomy fields so I use the query:

```
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('TaxonomyHiddenList')/Items?$filter=Term%20eq%20'test'
```

To get the taxonomy object and I can update my library item using a JSON body like this:

```
...
"MyTaxoField":{
  "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue"},
  "Label":"test",
  "TermGuid":"16d0126b-02df-44cc-8b22-a78bd153ecc0",
  "WssId":"-1"
}
...
```

But sometime, the taxonomy value doesn't exist yet; So I have to create it before updating my Item.

Do you know how to do it with REST api?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates how to create a term under a term set using its ID.

To begin, you'll need the GUIDs for both the group and the term set.

**Uri**

```
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox/_api/v2.1/termStore/termGroups/<<GroupId>>/termSets/<<TermSetId>>/children
```

please update `<<GroupId>>` with your Group GUID and `<<TermSetId>>` with your Termset GUID.

**Body**

```
{  
    "labels": [  
        {  
            "name": "New Term Title",  
            "isDefault": true,  
            "languageTag": "en-US"  
        }  
    ],  
    "descriptions": [  
        {  
            "description": "New Term Description",  
            "languageTag": "en-US"  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

Please be aware that in order to proceed with this example, it is crucial to have an already existing group and term set. Before proceeding, please ensure that you have identified the appropriate group and term set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I tried the request you sent but I got this error: "v2.1/termStore/groups/429b0bd3-ca9b-4a6f-b69a-fd7be34b414e/sets/1f2a5961-7396-4cff-b8a5-b185347e2154/children" is not valid.

Comment: `_api/v2.1/termStore/termGroups/bd3b7025-bcce-4a92-bd8a-b6b21ff24d9a/termSets/1f2a5961-7396-4cff-b8a5-b185347e2154/children` Try with this one, this is working for me so I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: Ok, I modified my request to get all the values: `https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox/_api/v2.1/termStore/termGroups/cfa10a33-3c7a-4fa2-9b04-f01150ddba27/termSets/04bc1061-109f-419a-ae46-eb5fe6d3460a/terms`. It works on my browser but when I tried in Postman, I got the "accessDenied" error and I didn't understand why... No I found what was wrong: the app permission you create to have your client id/secret should contains the permission to access Taxonomy. When you have this, it works fine !!! thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it worked for you!